# Select Entity property in related table using linq

Tags: c#, linq

here is my setup.

**Base Model**

```
public class Base
{
    public int BaseID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(8)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string BaseNumber { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BillOfMaterial> billOfMaterials { get; set; }
}
```

**BillOfMaterial Model**

```
public class BillOfMaterial
{
    public int BillOfMaterialID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string BomNumber { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Base> Bases { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to do is select all bill of material BomNumbers where the base is equal to a input base number.

**What I have tried**

```
BaseNumber = "A1C1D001";

var BOMQuery = (from Base in db.Bases.Include("BillOfMaterials")
                where Base.BaseNumber == BaseNumber
                select Base.billOfMaterials.ToList());
```

When trying to create this query I can't see the BomNumber property when I do => select Base.BillOfMaterials.(Can't Find Property)

I tried using the .Include() extension to try and bring in the related table in hopes it would give me the property. Not sure how to word this question exactly to do a good google search for the answer. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: It looks like there is a many-to-many relationship between Base and BillOfMaterial. Is that the intended relationship?

Comment: Yes it is, a base can have many bill of materials, and a bill of material can be a part of many bases.

Comment: Where do you want to use Base.billOfMaterials.   In the "where" or in the "select"?

Comment: In the select @Aldert

Comment: I want to do Select Base.billOfMaterials.BomNumber where Base.BaseNumber == "A1C1D001"

Comment: This is logical because the billOfMaterials property is of type ICollection. So you have more than one BillOfMaterial and therefor more BomNumbers. So you do not get only one back.

Comment: @Aldert yes exactly, I want to get multiple back. But when I can't figure out how to create the linq query to do so.

Comment: @Aldert I figured it out, I had to use a ,SelectMany before the second select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you only need a list of BOMs use the following:

```
var BOMQuery = db.Bases
              .Where(x => x.BaseNumber == BaseNumber)
              .SelectMany(a => a.billOfMaterials.Select(b => b.BomNumber)).ToList();
```

You can then add it to an ObservableCollection like this:

```
BomList = new ObservableCollection<string>(BOMQuery);
```

Comment: Oh! I had no idea you had to project a second time with another select.

Comment: The power of Linq, once you get used to it it makes perfect sense.

Comment: u can use it in a foreach and add to Obs.Coll like: foreach (string oneBom in BOMQuery). The IQueryable is an object what steps through the result set so it is not a double loop.

Comment: Yeah I tried that actually and it says can't convert List<string> to string. That is why it was throwing me for such a loop because I figured I could loop through with a foreach statement. @Aldert

Comment: Tried that and it said can't convert IEnumerable<string> to a string O.o @Aldert

Comment: leaving out the ToList() and having it in the foreach to add to Obs. Coll should not cause a problem?

Comment: Yeah I tried that exactly. I am getting a the same issue still. the BOMQuery type is IQueryable<IEnumerable<string>>. I expected this to just return an IEnumerable<string> @Aldert

Comment: Great job, can you edit the answer accordingly so we have it good for other readers?

Comment: Thanks again @Aldert for the help and sticking with me to figure it out!